# Difference between accessing bits after initializing multiple-bit registers forwards vs. backwards in Verilog

Tags: verilog

New Verilog user here. I was doing some exercises and needed to use some logic which made me wonder this. Here is some relevant code:

```
reg [7:0] a;
reg [0:7] b;
a[2] = 1'b1;
b[2] = 1'b1;
```

Would 'a' now be 00100000, or 00000100? I'm guessing 'b' would be 00100000, is that correct?

Comment: the code above will not compile.

Comment: @Serge I know.. it was just a simple basic understanding question, not real code snippet :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The range [7:0] means the MSB is 7 and the LSB is 0. So `a` would be 00000100

A few extra lines of code would give you your answer without needing to ask:

```
module top;
reg [7:0] a;
reg [0:7] b;
initial begin
  a[2] = 1'b1;
  b[2] = 1'b1;
  $displayb(a,,b);
end 
endmodule
```